# How to get a live preview for material library?

Tags: materials

I'm a completely noob to blender, I was looking for materials in material library and found out I have to select a material and click on "preview material" to see what it's appearance is like. Is there any option to get an instant preview of the material instead of clicking on both names and preview option? I've seen some guys having materials with previews at the bottom portion of their blender window on some youtube videos! (ps I was using Keyshot, that's why I found its very disturbing to do 2 clicks and waiting for preview of each material just to find out how does it look like.)

Answer (score 1):

When you press Z, you'll see the 4 viewport options (render, solid, wire, and material), select the material option and boom, you'll be able to preview your materials in the 3D viewport. You can also hold Z, hover your mouse the viewport you want to view, then let go of Z (that's a faster way if you are always quickly switching between viewports).